# object.class returns unexpected results in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `descendants` method in my `Question` model to return all objects that inherit from it.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def descendants
      ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select do |klass|
        klass < self
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `Question.descendants` I get back an array w/ a single object

```
[MultipleChoice(id: integer, text: text, scored: boolean, required: boolean, type: string, questionnaire_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)]
```

The problem is that when I call `Question.descendants.first.class` I get back `Class` instead of the expected `MultipleChoice`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, that you already have a class in the array (the `MultipleChoice` class). When you ask `Question.descendants.first` you get that `MultipleChoice` class.

However, you are asking for `Question.descendants.first**.class**`. And the class of `MultipleChoice` is `Class`.

Getting `Class` as the class of `MultipleChoice` is perfectly OK. Have a look at the ruby metamodel as a reference:

[image: diagram of ruby metamodel]

image source: http://sermoa.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/ruby-classes-and-superclasses/

Answer (score 0):

You have `MultipleChoice` class instead of instance in your array returned by `descendants` method. This is because you used `ObjectSpace.each_object` with `Class` parameter, which returns classes, since their class is `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[MultipleChoice(id: integer, text: text, scored: boolean, required: boolean, type: string, questionnaire_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)]
```

This is not an array of single object. This is an array in which you have something like `[MultipleChoice]`. And when you try `MultipleChoice.class` it will return `Class`.

There is some issue in your code that creates `Question.descendants`